# C# difference betweeen ex.StackTrace vs ex.toString()?

Tags: c#, exception

What is the difference between ex.StackTrace vs ex.toString() for exceptions in C#/.NET?  Does toString() include also the message and the StackTrace?

Comment: This could've easily been answerd by trying both and comparing.

Comment: no because im asking about StackTrace not Message

Comment: Have you read the documents on [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.stacktrace?view=net-6.0) and [Exception.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.tostring?view=net-6.0)? If you want further clarification of the `Exception.ToString`, you could check out the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,430) of what it includes...

Answer (score 1):

From the `Exception.ToString` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.tostring?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> The default implementation of `ToString` obtains the name of the class that threw the current exception, the message, the result of calling `ToString` on the inner exception, and the result of calling `Environment.StackTrace`. If any of these members is `null`, its value is not included in the returned string.
>
> If there is no error message or if it is an empty string (""), then no error message is returned. The name of the inner exception and the stack trace are returned only if they are not `null`.